# Seeding a stim.TableauSimulator

Tags: programming, stim

When creating a sampler from a `stim.Circuit` (say, for example, using `stim.Circuit.compile_sampler`), one can provide a `seed` to the random number generator to make sure the simulation is reproducible.

However, I am looking at an error model that requires me to manually apply operations to a `stim.TableauSimulator` instead. Is there a way/workaround to also allow me to seed the random number generator used by the `stim.TableauSimulator.measure`?

Answer (score 2):

Since v1.10, you can give a `seed` argument to `stim.TableauSimulator.__init__`:

```
import stim

shots = []
for _ in range(5):

    # Make seeded simulator.
    simulator = stim.TableauSimulator(seed=5)

    simulator.h(*range(10))
    shots.append(simulator.measure_many(*range(10)))

for shot in shots:
    print(shot)
    assert shot == shots[0]
```